# how to read date from calendar in MVC into Model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Model properties

```
 public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime SelectedDateTo { get; set; }
```

The view has

```
<input id="Testdate-Field" type="text"  style="width: 125px;" value="@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.SelectedDate)" /> To
   <input id="TestdateTo-Field" type="text"  style="width: 125px;" value="@Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.SelectedDateTo)" />
```

To show the calendar in the view I have

```
  $("#Testdate-Field").bind("click", function(event) {       
     $( "#Testdate-Field").datepicker();
    });    

      $("#TestdateTo-Field").bind("click", function(event) {       
     $( "#TestdateTo-Field").datepicker();
    });
```

Now, 2 problems

1. When I click in the input box for the first time, the calendar doesn't appear till I click somewhere else and then in the input box for date.
2. When I pick a date from the calendars my model properties SelectedDate and SelectedDateTo do not change and remain the default values when I read them. What do I need to do to read the input dates?

---Update---
Added this in ready as per the suggestion

```
 $("#Testdate-Field").datepicker();
 $("#TestdateTo-Field").datepicker();
```

and the first problem is solved! Now how do I bind what I have selected in the datefield to my model properties?

Comment: firstly initialize #TestdateTo-Field in ready DOM model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, do not put your .datepicker() code in the bind event.  Simply execute those on document ready:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $( "#Testdate-Field").datepicker();
        $( "#TestdateTo-Field").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

For your second question, use Html helpers to generate your inputs and then in your controller you can easily bind them: instead of using DisplayTextFor inside of input tags YOU generate, use TextBoxFor to generate the input tags for you:

ViewModel:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    // other properties here
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SelectedDateTo { get; set; }
    // other properties here
}
```

View:

```
@model SampleClassViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDate, new { class = "datepickers" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDateTo, new { class = "datepickers" })
    <input type="submit" />
}
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $( ".datepickers").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

There are many way to bind your properties, here are a couple...
Controller option 1:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeControllerAction(SampleViewModel model)
{
    // do work...
}
```

Controller option 2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
    var model = SomeServiceMethodToBuildModel();
    this.TryUpdateModel(model);
    // do work...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That worked! So, for problem 2 how do I bind what I select from the date picker to my model date properties? I have written in my question the two lines I have in view.